# How to automatically update cookies

Tags: javascript, session-cookies

I'm not an english native speaker, I'm sorry if what I say make you confused. Thanks.

I'm crawing something from a website recently.The normal operation steps should be as follows:

1. I log on to this website
2. I jump to a subpage
3. I click a button (actually it executes a JS function)
4. The website return something

But this is inconvenient, because I  always need to open the browser to complete these steps. So I found the XHR of step3 in F12 and copied it to a curl command to loop through.
This is much simpler than before, but I still need to log in with a broswer and copy the latest cookie to update my curl command.

Supposing that Step1 and Step3 are actually XHRs, and I know what the args mean.
My question is, how can I get the latest cookies without using a browser, I mean, a real browser software (which I think is the only problem to be solved)? Or is there anything else I don't know that needs to be done?

Comment: Cookies are stored in a browser.  So it is unclear how you would get cookies without the browser.  Unless you are wanting to go through all the steps with a rest client, generating the web requests, to then grab the cookies off of the headers.

Comment: Can I do this by simulating the behavior of a browser, such as using some Python packages. I mean, can I not really open a browser software of my computer.

Comment: Any non-browser language that can generate web requests can mimic a browser and grab headers off of the responses.

Comment: In fact, I don't know much about cookies. When I tried to use curl, one thing puzzled me. When I copied the XHR of login to curl, I noticed that there was a cookie in the copied command. Is this cookie from an old access? If I simulate a web request, when will I get the cookie? I'm sorry I asked a very basic question

Comment: If you are sending a cookie, then that would signify that you already have it.  A response can also contain new cookies in the response header.  I would encourage you to do some research into the format of http requests and responses.  In particular, the structure of their headers, which is where cookies are transfered.

Answer (score 0):

A typical login consists of a `post-request` that is sent to the server. The payload typically contains the username and password in plain text like it was sent from a `html-form`. The answer from the server then contains the session-cookie (sometimes called `PHPSESSID` or similar) in its header.

The session-cookie can then be used to place further requests.

Sometimes the session-cookie is already set before you login, but only becomes active upon logging in. Generally you will get a new session-cookie every time you connect.

Some websites deploy technologies like `google-nocaptcha-recaptcha` that prevent bots from logging in at all, just so you know.